# NLTK shows grammatically wrong tags, what will be the correct POS Tags?

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

What will be the POS Tags for:

```
The poor can can can the tomatoes.
```

NLTK shows grammatically wrong tags:

```
[('The', 'DT'), ('poor', 'JJ'), ('can', 'MD'), ('can', 'MD'), ('can', 'MD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('tomatoes', 'NNS'), ('.', '.')]
```

Comment: It shows the same for me too, I tried it

Comment: grammatically its wrong :)

Comment: You should read more carefully, @alvas. The question is about grammar, not about programming. The "correct" tags are: the first "can" is a noun, the second is a modal, the third is a regular verb ("to put things in cans").

Comment: Ah, now I see it... But yes, this is a BIBI https://bibinlp.umiacs.umd.edu/ question... So still not SO question.